# Streaming audio from a web interface

Tags: audio, webserver, streaming, media

### What I Want To Do

Allow anyone with the public IP for my **EC2 Instance** to browse and listen to a collection of radio programs I record live.

**Requirements**

- All setup possible through CLI (since the instance is on AWS)
- A web interface for user interaction
- Browser, listen, and (optionally) download audio files

### What I've Already Tried

- [Plex](https://plex.tv/) -- Plex was great but I don't want to make people sign up for an account and I don't want to pay for a subscription when I'm only using it for one thing.
- [Kodi/XBMC](http://kodi.tv/) -- Would be my choice but I can't set it up [without a hardware-accelerated display](http://kodi.wiki/view/Web_interface) ( I have tried setting up vnc xdisplay but it still won't start)
- Apache -- This is an okay solution but I'd rather have a real web interface rather than just a directory of files that can be downloaded.

So can I get some direction on what else to attempt? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure it does what you need, but take a look at [Logitech Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Media_Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [mstream](http://mstream.io/) which satisfied all of my requirements. Took less than 5 minutes to [setup via CLI](https://github.com/IrosTheBeggar/mStream/blob/master/docs/install.md). Worked liked a charm.